React Router Future Flag Warning in Remix Vite app
I'm using Remix with a modern npx create-remix@latest (cloudflare) template. It uses React router under the hood (Remix does), but I don't explicitly use React router anywhere in my code.
Now I get this warning:

⚠️ React Router Future Flag Warning: The revalidation behavior after
4xx/5xx action responses is changing in v7. You can use the
v7_skipActionErrorRevalidation future flag to opt-in early. For more
information, see
https://reactrouter.com/v6/upgrading/future#v7_skipactionerrorrevalidation.

Clicking on the link gives me suggestions on how to edit the  component to fix this, but I don't have such a component in my app.
These are my de(relevant) pendencies:
"@remix-run/cloudflare": "^2.11.1",
"@remix-run/cloudflare-pages": "^2.11.1",
"@remix-run/react": "^2.11.1",
"remix-utils": "^7.6.0",

What do I do to make these warning logs go away / to fix this?

These are just warnings about future features so in all likelihood you can probably ignore them. Have you checked the Remix.run docs on configurability?

Yes this was my thinking too. I kind of live and die with console messages haha, but I understand that a little wait will probably do the trick.

It seems that React-Router-DOM v6.28.0 added some warnings:

v6.28.0

Date: 2024-11-06
What's Changed

In preparation for v7 we've added deprecation warnings for any future flags that you have not yet opted into. Please use the flags to
better prepare for eventually upgrading to v7.


These are just "warnings" about future features so in all likelihood you can probably completely ignore them. This is due to the way that Remix.run and React-Router share some common core.
It appears you can pass the future flags via your vite config.
For complete details see:

Remix.run Future Flags
Remix Vite Plugin Config

As per the warning you can apparently opt-in to the router's v7_skipActionErrorRevalidation feature early by enabling it in your config.
Example:
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    remix({
      ....,
      future: {
        /* any enabled future flags */
        v7_skipActionErrorRevalidation: true, // <-- early opt-in
      },
      ....,
    }),
  ],
});


This is indeed the place where I can add feature flags (there are v3_ flags present there). It still doesn't remove the warning at this point, but thanks for pointing me to this file, for this particular log I'll just sit it out :)

@Sventies Yeah, I tried to provide as much an answer without outright saying something crazy like "this is how you remove the warning". Based on the messaging it reads more informational to me than anything "bad" is happening.

@Sventies The Remix.run/React-Router-DOM landscape is also becoming quite muddled. I thought it at least a little bit odd that you'd see RRDv7 future flag "warnings" when you are using Remix v2. I've read a few of their blogs that basically state that RRDv7 and Remix v3 will effectively be the same thing, and Remix only ships the extra bits for Server-Side-Rendering. So in that regard, I guess I shouldn't be surprised that future feature flags bleed over a bit.

@Sventies And React-Router 7 dropped yesterday. Looking through the CHANGELOG.md I noticed that for version 6.28.0 they "added deprecation warnings for any future flags that you have not yet opted into. Please use the flags to better prepare for eventually upgrading to v7", which is what I think you ran into.

FYI: I am using react vite and install latesh react-router-dom
npm install react-router-dom@latest

To remove the warnings and make the app compatible with React Router v7, I enabled the recommended future flags explicitly in both the createBrowserRouter and RouterProvider.


import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import PageNotFound from "./pages/PageNotFound";

// Configure the router with future flags enabled
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
    { path: "/", element: <Navigate to="/login" /> }, // Redirect to "/login"
    { path: "/login", element: <Login /> },
    { path: "/home", element: <Home /> },
    { path: "*", element: <PageNotFound /> }, // Fallback for unknown routes
  ],
  {
    future: {
      v7_relativeSplatPath: true, // Enables relative paths in nested routes
      v7_fetcherPersist: true,   // Retains fetcher state during navigation
      v7_normalizeFormMethod: true, // Normalizes form methods (e.g., POST or GET)
      v7_partialHydration: true, // Supports partial hydration for server-side rendering
      v7_skipActionErrorRevalidation: true, // Prevents revalidation when action errors occur
    },
  }
);

function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider
      future={{ v7_startTransition: true }} // Enables React's startTransition API
      router={router}
    />
  );
}

export default App;



